# Get URL pk in django forms.py

Tags: django, forms

I have this URL

```
path('private/productores/<pk>', views.Productor_Private.as_view()),
```

Views.py

```
class Productor_Private(generic.DetailView):
    model = Productor
    template_name = 'firstpage/productor_private.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        form = RepartoForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = RepartoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

I want to retrieve the pk from the URL to use it as a filter inside the forms.py, to do something like this:

```
class RepartoForm(forms.Form):
    productos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.filter(productor=pk))
```

So in other words, I need to check what the current user's "productor" id is in order to only retrieve the "productos" that belong to this "productor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to "patch" the form constructor, and manually set the `queryset` in the `__init__` function:

```
class RepartoForm(forms.Form):
    productos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, productor_pk=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if productor_pk is not None:
            self.fields['productos'].queryset = Producto.objects.filter(
                productor=productor_pk
            )
```

Or for older versions of Python that does not implement more advanced parameter unpacking, one can implement it like:

```
class RepartoForm(forms.Form):
    productos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        productor_pk = kwargs.pop('productor_pk', None)
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if productor_pk is not None:
            self.fields['productos'].queryset = Producto.objects.filter(
                productor=productor_pk
            )
```

In case no `product_pk` is given, the queryset are *all* the `Producto`s (in case you do not want that, you can alter the form, and for example by default use an *empty* `QuerySet` like `Producto.objects.none()`).

Then in the view, you can construct the form with a *named* `productor_pk` parameter:

```
class Productor_Private(generic.DetailView):
    model = Productor
    template_name = 'firstpage/productor_private.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        form = RepartoForm(productor_pk=pk)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = RepartoForm(request.POST, productor_pk=pk)

        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

> **Note**: you also need to cover the case where the form is *invalid*: right now `post` will return `None` for that, but you should return a HTTP response for *all* codepaths.

Comment: @user6148356: is this by any chance Python-2.x?

Comment: @user6148356: updated with a working version for Python-2.x. Note that on January 1, 2020, the support of Python-2.x ends.

Comment: Nope, version 3.6.4

Comment: @user6148356: sorry made a typo, should now be fixed.

Comment: productor_pk still returns none, so the filter doesn't work (it displays all productos)

Comment: @user6148356 can you print the `pk` in the view? Shouldn't you specify the type? so `<int:pk>` instead of `<pk>`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. in views.py in get you need to pass productor_pk to RepartoForm. So like form=RepartoForm(productor_pk)

Comment: @user6148356: aargh, yes you are right. Updated it.